# Vendor RAM vs offical form RAM

Tags: hp, memory, hp-proliant

I want add RAM for our server HP Proliant DL380 G6. 
There are no HP's shop in my country. Some computer & server shop offer me Kingston RAM for my server. But my boss says "Only HP!".

What's difference between official ram and global ram?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HERE](http://h40059.www4.hp.com/warranty/information/faq.php#31)'s HP's comment on the matter. Basically you can use non-HP memory but there are caveats.

Answer (score 6):

Technically speaking, there's no difference. Practically speaking, though, HP will likely refuse to perform any warranty work on the server if non-HP RAM is installed or at the very least, will require you to remove the third-party RAM and reproduce the problem before they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, where did you buy the server from? Couldn't you purchase from the same place? It's quite possible to order HP RAM from a variety of sources. Either way, there's no technical difference between HP RAM and Kingston or Crucial, etc. There's likely a cost difference, with the HP RAM being potentially more expensive than the alternatives, but in general, it's relatively inexpensive these days.

Comment: Co-worker guy who was a system administrator bought server from England. There is no document about how he bought server from England, maybe lost.